# After creating python exe file with cx_freeze the file doesn't do anything

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I recently created used cx_freeze to create a python 3.2.2 exe file. When I tried to run the exe file nothing happened.

Here is the code for my test.py file:

```
print("hello world")

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

Here is the code for my testSetup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

exe = Executable(
   script="test.py",
   base="Win32GUI",
   targetName="Test.exe"
   )


setup(
    name = "Test",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "I wish programming was this easy",
    executables = [exe])
```

The build directory that cx_freeze made has a folder called exe.win32-3.2 which has the files:

bz2.pyd 
library.zip 
python32.dll 
Test.exe 
unicodedata.pyd

Comment: I guess  clicking that .exe must've opened some command prompt?

Comment: If you're doing this from a windows computer, then [p2exe](http://py2exe.org/) is a lot easier

Comment: it didn't open a command prompt.

Comment: p2exe doesn't work with python 3.2.2

Comment: What version of cx_Freeze have you got? If it's less than 4.3, start by updating it.

Answer (score 21):

My suggestion:

1. set `base = None` (try it: maybe that's all you want? `base = Win32GUI` does "hide" the console - this is useful when you're building a GUI)
2. In the same folder with your .exe make a batch-file (a text-file with .bat) calling your .exe:

this goes into your batch-file:

```
name-of-your-app.exe %1

PAUSE
```

You'll start your app by clicking the batch-file - it keeps the console open so you're able to reed the errors/output.

Comment: I had the same problem, once I set `base = None` the .exe started printing on console.

Comment: got this error: `cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named None`

Answer (score 4):

Place a `input()` at the bottom of your code, and try again:

Looks like your `.exe` runs and exists before you can see anything, so place a `input()` at the bottom to make the script wait for user input before exiting.

```
print("hello world")

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
input()
```

Comment: I put input() at the bottom of my code and ran it, but then an error popped up that said:  
Cannot import traceback module.  
Exception: No module named re  
Original Exception: input(): lost sys.stdin

Comment: @AshiwiniChuadhary I did what the link said to do, but then it threw an error because of input. So then I removed the input line and it's back to doing nothing or the command prompt is disappearing too fast to see it.

Comment: @SnakeP that's weird, try running the .exe through cmd itself try with `input()` removed.

Comment: @AshiwiniChuadhary I tried it in the cmd itself and with input() it still threw an error and without it, it didn't print anything.

Comment: @AshiwiniChuadhary the error it threw said: Traceback(most recent call last): File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py",line27,in<module>exec(code,m._dict_)File"test.py",line 7, in<module>RuntimeError:input():lost sys.stdin